# How does a programmer uninstall a Google Play App they have made to reinstall the new version without it negatively effecting stats?

Tags: google-play, installation, uninstallation

I am noticing some adverse effects on my Google Play Stats because I, as the programmer, am uninstalling the old version of the app to reinstall the new version immediately.

Basically I am on 5 installs and 10 uninstalls. Its only me that knows about the program yet.

I have learned this negatively effects Store Search algorithms when it gets released to the public.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options.

1. Stop using the Play store for quick iterations. Install your app using adb on your development device.
2. Stop uninstalling. Why uninstall and re-install? Why not just increase the version code?
3. Use a play store internal test track for your updates. Increasing the version code for each upload. This won't be visible to any users, as long as you don't change the version string. The version code is a 32 bit integer, so even if you did it 10 times a day, it would take you allmost 600,000 years before you ran out of version codes.